# Detect installed languages in Navision 2018 CU2 database

Tags: database, t-sql, navision

I would like to detect the languages installed in Navision 2018, using direct access to database tables using T-SQL, in order to translate content in company tables in localized language.

For now I am able to extract all the metadata about tables i need, using the [Metadata] field from table [dbo].[Object Metadata] and deflating it:

```
SELECT 
    o.[Name],
    m.[Object Type],
    m.[Metadata], -- XML Metadata
    m.[User Code], -- C# Metadata
    m.[User AL Code] -- C/AL Metadata
FROM [Navision].[dbo].[Object Metadata] AS m
JOIN [Navision].[dbo].[Object] AS o
ON m.[Object ID] = o.[ID]
```

When I get the XML from the table metadata, it contains field metadata with localized content:

```
Name="Posting Date" CaptionML="DAN=Bogføringsdato;ENU=Posting Date"
```

Right now I detect the installed languages by looking at the language codes in the `CapitonML` attribute, but I want a better approach detecting languages installed in Navision 2018.

Is there a table or other metadata information containing the languages installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure what you mean by detect. Esch object is translated individually. So if table 3 contains Danish translation and table 4 contains Russian, what would you want to detect?

Anyway there are [powershell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.dynamics.nav.model.tools/export-navapplicationobjectlanguage?view=businesscentral-ps) to handle transition, maybe they will help you.

Alternatively you could use [xlif format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/lifecycle-services/use-translation-service) for translation.

Any of the two is better than messing with metadata.